# Can ReSharper remove blank lines before and/or after single line statements?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, resharper

Are there any code formatting options in ReSharper to make this code:

```
public string PublicMethod1(string parameter)
{
    parameter += "Hello";

    parameter += " ";

    parameter += "world!";

    return parameter;
}
```

look like this:

```
public string PublicMethod1(string parameter)
{
    parameter += "Hello";
    parameter += " ";
    parameter += "world!";
    return parameter;
}
```

I am currently using Visual Studio Professional 2019 and ReSharper 2021.3.2. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, set option [Keep max blank lines in code](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Reference__Options__Languages__CSharp__Formatting_Style__Blank_Lines.html) to `0`:

ReSharper > Options > Code Editing > C# > Formatting Style > Blank Lines

Value `3`:

```
void Method() {
  foo();



  foo();
}
```

Value `0`:

```
void Method()
{
    foo();
    foo();
}
```